# Possible to open an eclipse project from external application?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been working on a project and it would be much more convenient to the end-user if I was to install the software, and have an Icon for "Editing" their project.

The software that I'm working on is a Server Library, and I'm installing a basic setup of the server with an executable, and checking the update server and updating the Library at runtime when required.

I was curious as to if there was a way to open a Eclipse Project by passing arguments into a command, or something.

Example:

```
../server/
-- RunServer.exe
-- EditServer.exe
/server/project/
---- Eclipse Project Files
```

and open the project that's in /server/project/ when `EditServer.exe` is ran.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible.

If the software you are developing is a java application you could however export a runnable jar file which your end user can run by simply double clicking.

Comment: Well, I already have all of that, I just figured it would be easier for people if they could just open a launcher that sets the project up for them opposed to them setting the project up themselves.

Comment: So you want to automate the import of a project into eclipse?